# Show a message after certain commits are pulled in Git

Tags: git

Some commits require certain commands to be ran after pulling. For example, if I install a new package and record that installation to a file (e.g. `package.json` or `Gemfile`), everyone who pulls that commit will need to install that package too. I could use Git hooks, but everyone on the team would need to install those hooks. Is there a way to make Git display a message when pulling certain commits? These messages would be tracked as part of the repo.

E.g. when you pull a commit that adds something to `package.json`, it can display a message saying "package.json changed, run `yarn install` to download new pages".

Comment: No, but you could build it into your app startup/build à la database migrations.

Comment: @Ry could you share any info on what that might look like? Tools, etc that could be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an inappropriate use of version control. Not only for the reasons you mentioned, but because there's other reasons these files might change other than `git pull`. And because `git` is not setup to take care of these sorts of tasks.

This is a task for your build tool. It is exactly the tool for these tasks.

In your example, you could add a dependency to check if `Gemfile` has changed and do a `bundle install` to applicable `rake` tasks. Or if you're not comfortable with running the command, `rake` would display a message about the problem and how it should be fixed. This could even be controlled with an environment variable.

You could also add a `rake` task which does a `git pull` and then runs the necessary commands to ensure the build is in good shape.